# Symfony doctrine concurrence query and actions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using [Symfony](https://symfony.com) with [Doctine](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) and I have a problem of concurrency:

```
//I wish to do a lock about the tuple $accountBank or tables in order to do some actions on it
$accountBank = getAccountBankUser("Charlie");
if ($account->getSold() > 0) $account->setSold() = $account->getSold() - x;
//I wish to do a unlock about the tuple $accountBank or tables
```

The problem is that there are some servers a one database. I wish to read and modify the real amount of money but without the lock it is not possible. For instance: there are two server A e B and works in parallel way:

```
//Server A
$accountBank = getAccountBankUser("Charlie");
if ($account->getSold() > 0) //$account->getSold() is 6 so the if is true;
{
    sleep(20); //The server B finish its jobs and now the condition is not valid ($account->getSold() =-4.
    $account->setSold() = $account->getSold() - 10;
}


//Server B
$accountBank = getAccountBankUser("Charlie");
if ($account->getSold() > 0) {
    $account->setSold() = $account->getSold() - 10;
}
```

I search a solution to avoid it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is pessimistic locking. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#pessimistic-locking

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but how can you use function on the left side of assgnment?
Should it be something like this? `$account->setSold($account->getSold() - 10);`

Comment: if these scripts are triggered by a frontend, a way could be using websockets to lock the functionality "client-side"

Comment: @Johny In Doctrine there are the entity, variables with set and get to describe the class.  I use them (set and get) to get and set the variable. What do you mean with "on left side"

Comment: @johnSmith Can you do an example. I have not understood. Thanks

Comment: @JulienB. I have read the doc but I have not understood very well for this reason I have ask here

Comment: regarding Johny's comment: assignments can only be done to variables, not functions. so either `...->setSold($newvalue)` or `->sold = $newValue`, but never ever `->setSold() = $newvalue`.

Comment: at your level of knowledge, you should do locking. read about "lost update", "dirty reads", and other problems that database locking was made for, read about how to avoid deadlocks, read about transactions. You're approaching your problem as if it was extremely simple, but without locking, it's hard and you should know your stuff.

Comment: "left side of assignment" means everything that goes before "=" sign.
Please pay attention on @Jakumi's comment, he clarified my thought.